# Anything better than "weltweit" for "All over the world"?

Tags: phrase, usage, idiom

I would like to say something like, "You have really lived all over the world!" ...like in response to someone saying they've been to many different countries.

I did a Google search for this and only found *weltweit* as a translation, which seemed a little flat to me.

Is there a better way to say "all over the world"?  Would *auf der ganzen Welt* be the closest thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that “weltweit” doesn’t sound good here. “Auf der ganzen Welt” and “überall auf der Welt” are fine:

> Du hast wirklich schon überall auf der Welt gelebt!
>
> Sie haben wirklich schon auf der ganzen Welt gelebt!

The “schon” is not strictly necessary, but it makes the sentence flow better.

Answer (score -1):

Gegen

> Er hat schon weltweit Wohnungen gehabt.

spricht meines Erachtens nicht das geringste.

Comment: Würde in einen behördlichen Bericht sicher passen. Sonst eher nicht.

Comment: @chirlu: Wieso nicht? Wegen des `Wohnsitzes`? Er hat schon weltweit Erfahrungen als Fußballer gesammelt. Sie hat weltweit die Charts gestürmt. Das Buch war ein weltweiter Erfolg. Usw. ad infinitam.

Comment: Ja, der Kanzleiton kommt vor allem durch „Wohnsitze”. Aber auch davon abgesehen ist „weltweit“ eher sachlich. Für deine Aussagesätze vollkommen OK, die könnten in der Zeitung so stehen (wobei ich die Verbindung mit den gestürmten Charts stilistisch nicht so gelungen fände, aber die typische Zeitung würde es trotzdem drucken). Aber in einen ausdrücklich unsachlichen, erstaunt-begeisterten Ausruf paßt es nicht.

Comment: @chirlu: Das ist Dein persönlicher Geschmack, aber nichts, was Du verallgemeinern kannst.

Comment: Hm - also ich stelle mir das so vor: Ich habe ein Date und will ein bisschen prahlen und erzähle dann so, dass ich schon in Amerika gewohnt habe und in Thailand und in Australien und so weiter. Also eigentlich auf jedem Kontinent. Und dann sagt dieses hübsche, süße Mädel bewundernd: "Du hast ja schon weltweit Wohnsitze gehabt!". Echt jetzt? Und ich denke, dass der Kontext, den der OP sich vorstellt, ganz ähnlich ist. Und ich denke weiterhin, dass die Antwort des Mädels wohl eher wäre: "Du hast ja echt schon überall mal gewohnt!"

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Du kaprizierst Dich zu sehr auf die Wohnsitze. Es geht aber um `weltweit`.

Comment: Du hast aber noch keinen Satz ohne „Wohnsitze“ vorgeschlagen. „Du hast ja wirklich schon weltweit gewohnt“? Klingt für meine Ohren nicht gut.

Comment: Ja, ich denke `weltweit` würde man eher sagen, wenn man zeitgleich Wohnungen über die ganze Welt verstreut hat. "Ich wohne weltweit" wäre dann richtig. Bei Wohnungen, die man sequentiell bewohnt, sagt man "auf der ganzen Welt". Im Eng. gibt es ja auch das Wort "worldwide", das kann man 1:1 übersetzen.

Comment: @userunknown Nö. Der OP hat als Beispiel den Wohnsitz angegeben, Du hast ein Beispiel mit Wohnsitz gemacht und ich sage Dir, dass Dein Beispiel im Alltag doof klingt. Ich kommentiere nur Dein Beispiel. Du kannst gerne noch ein anderes machen.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Der OP hat `Wohnsitz` nicht benutzt. Ich habe bereits berlinweit gewohnt - andere mögen weltweit gewohnt haben. `Wohnungen gehabt` klingt halb wie Eigentum daran gehabt, was sein kann, aber ich weiß es nicht. `Bewohnt` wäre eine andere Alternative, oder gemietet.